# ошибка когда больше 7 символов

Tags: java, массивы

Почему выдаётся ошибка, когда пишешь на команде больше 7 символов?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Encrypted {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner t = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);    

        String text, key;
        byte[] result = new byte[1000];

        System.out.print("Введите текст для зашифровки: ");
        text = t.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Введите 4 значный ключ шифрования с пробелами: ");
        key = k.nextLine();
        //System.out.println();

        System.out.println(key);

        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            byte[] text_byte = text.getBytes();
            byte[] key_byte = key.getBytes();

            //if (key_byte[i])
            result[i] = (byte) (text_byte[i] + key_byte[i]);
            //System.out.print("\n" + (text_byte[i]));
            String c_str = new String(result);
            System.out.print(c_str);
            //System.out.print("\n" + (result[i]));

            result[i] = 0;
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

---

```
Введите текст для зашифровки: 12345678
Введите 4 значный ключ шифрования с пробелами: 1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
b                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
R                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
e                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
T                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
h                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
V                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
k
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
>     at Encrypted.main(Encrypted.java:29)

Answer (score 1):

Всё просто:

когда ты вводишь ключ: `1 2 3 4`, то длина массива `key_byte` равна 7, а не 8. Поэтому когда `i = 7`, то `key_byte[i]` выкидывает ошибку.

Если же поставить в конце `1 2 3 4` пробел — то будет 8 элементов  и ошибки не будет.

Либо дозаполнять последний элемент массива байтом, либо придумывать еще что-то, чтобы работало как задумано

---

Все это ты бы мог сам увидеть банально включив отладчик и отладив свой код [Отладчик IntelliJ IDEA](http://learn.javajoy.net/debug-intellij-idea).

Comment: опять та же ошибка, но вместо 7 - 8 стоит. как сделать чтобы ключ когда закончился вернулся обратно???

Comment: @AbdullahHafizov это не правда.... всё работает как надо.. пруф http://ideone.com/x6ClrF  ...... ты не добавил пробел...

Comment: а тут больше 8 не работает http://ideone.com/fyJiHK

Comment: я думаю дело в том что, оно не возвращается обратно на первый символ ключа

Comment: @AbdullahHafizov ну так логично. у тебя цикл идет по количеству символов в `text`. а их гораздо больше чем в  `key`.... соответственно ошибка и вываливается, потому что у `key[i]` нет символа на той позиции........ тебе надо либо одинаковую длину делать, либо делать другой алгоритм, где не будет написано `text_byte[i] + key_byte[i]`

Comment: можете сказать какой нибудь алгоритм, я уже с этим запарился

Comment: @AbdullahHafizov алгоритм чего? вашей придуманной задачи? не имею понятия

Answer (score 0):

вы не правильно реализовали алгоритм нужен двойной цикл

```
` for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        byte[] text_byte = text.getBytes();
        byte[] key_byte = key.getBytes();

        for(int j=0; j<key_byte.lenght; j++)
            result[i] = (byte) (text_byte[i] + key_byte[j]);
        ....`
```

конечно при условии что я понял что вы хотите сделать, дайте алгоритм шифрования если я вас не понял

Comment: алгоритм таков, нужно создать программу, которая берет данные на входе и зашифровывает с помощью заданного ключа, соответственно я выбрал метод который берет код(UTF16) символов данных и прибавляет к коду(UTF16) ключа и выводит символ который получился при прибавлении, P.S надеюсь смог нормально объянить

Comment: @AbdullahHafizov ну вот код выше, ясли я вас так понял, к байту символа прибавляем ключь(набор  байтов), если нужно один байт символа и один байт ключа, тогда вам прсото ужно вводить ключь равным количеством символов

Comment: @AbdullahHafizov а ошибка в вашем коде, в том  что у вас массивы не равны